# Unit tests for a reverseString function

Tags: unit-testing

Please help me in generating the test cases for the following.I just have the following information: Please help me in getting started with writing test cases

```
reverseString(originalString, stringToBeReversed, stringReverseTo, max)
```

Comment: What are possible valid inputs?  Invalid inputs?

Comment: @Pedro: This is one of the interview questions and I do not ave any other information.But I assume valid inputs should be string and invalid inputs would be numbers please help

Comment: The declaratioin of your functioin is confusing. Why do you need both originalString and stringToBeReversed? And what is the usage of max? You shold ask the interviewer more about the specification of this functioin.

Comment: @easterbunny   the solutions i saw  is : reversestring('abcde', 'abc', 'opr', 2) but could not understand that... bt can you all help with me with any basic idea... if supposin  the basic idea is to check if the string is reversed  how can i go on about that

Answer (score 1):

First, write some happy path tests like:

empty string "",

tiny string "a",

input which count is odd "abc",

input which count is even "abcd"

...enough.

Then, unhappy path tests(invalid inputs for which you may throw exceptions):

nil, 123321, and so on.

Comment: for valid inputs you mean like reversestring("","","",1) and reversestring("a","a","a",1) reversestring("abc","abc","bc",1) and for invalid inputs reversestring(123321 123321,33,1)... something like this .... sorry can please show a testcase written...Thanks

Comment: I said i did'nt figure out why your function has so many arguments. If the basic idea is to check if the string is reversed, "" is a valid input.